# WP7 detect thread

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, process, detect

Is there any way that can detect which thread a line of code is in?

I'm working with Background Audio Agent and I want to detect what process and thread it is in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* that `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread` is available on WP7. You can use this to identify which thread you are on.

Check the docs here: [Thread.CurrentThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread.aspx)

Comment: I just checked and it is available.

Comment: Thanks @Rune Grimstad for the quick and correct response. It works

Comment: Also, how can I detect the process of a current task? Because I think the agent run in a different process

Comment: What do you mean with a differenc process? All WP7 apps run as one process and there is no communication between apps.

Comment: Every WP7 app can have a background agent, and I wonder if the agent runs in a different process ? Since I see it's hard to send data to the agent (Scheduled task, background audio)

Comment: Ah. Background agents. Didn't think of them... But, yeah. Afaik background agents run as separate processes.

Comment: so how can i destroy this agent process?

Comment: Normally you don't destroy it, it doesn't live for more than a few minutes. But I suggest you ask a new question about handling background processes, it is far beyond your original question on how to detect processes and threads :-)